# Django model convert IntegerField to ForeingKey keeping date

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, migration, models

I'm working in a project where I need to migrate an IntegerField to a ForeingKey to make it easier to do requests as: SKU_name, SKU_description, etc..

My models.py file has:

```
class BasketTable(models.Model):
    """Basket table."""

    SKU_Id = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="ID do SKU")
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Quantidade")
```

I'm trying to change `SKU_Id` to `SKU` field name, setting:

```
SKU = models.ForeignKey(SKUTable, db_column='Id', to_field='Id', null=True, verbose_name="ID do SKU")
```

My `SKU_Id` field has `unique=True` as needed according Django documentation.

So, after this change, I run `python manage.py makemigrations` command which results in:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='baskettable',
            name='SKU_Id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='baskettable',
            name='SKU',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='Id', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='products.SKUTable', to_field='Id', verbose_name='ID do SKU'),
        ),
    ]
```

So, I changed this migration file to:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='baskettable',
            name='SKU_Id',
            field=models.IntegerField(db_column='Id')
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='baskettable',
            old_name='SKU_Id',
            new_name='SKU',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='baskettable',
            name='SKU',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='Id', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                                    to='products.SKUTable', to_field='Id', verbose_name='ID do SKU'),
        ),
    ]
```

And after this, I run the command `python manage.py migrate` to save these changes.

The migration works and the data `SKU` and `SKU_id` can be accessed using `list_display` in my Admin, but when I try to access data as `SKU_name` or any other field, I got this error message:

```
SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'cil.models.BasketTableAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'SKU_Name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'BasketTableAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'cil.BasketTable'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

I hope that someone can make clear what I'm doing wrong when I try to get other table fields using the `list_display` or any other get function from models.

I used the following information to get here:

http://www.probthink.com/tech/converting-an-integer-id-field-to-foreign-key-field-without-data-migration/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

**Edit 1:**

I cleaned the code a little bit more.

One possible solution that I found is not change the name of the field and don't use db_column, instead, use to_field='destination_key_field'.

```
SKU = models.ForeignKey(SKUTable, to_field='Id', null=True, verbose_name="ID do SKU")
```

It is important to have null=True when working with this change.

Comment: Good question, but the code looks too long. Can you try to minimize the code by just showing the required ones.

Comment: `SKU_name` is not a field on your model. If you want to access the `name` of the `SKU` object, try `SKU.name`